# Why html entities are treated differently in different browsers?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, entity

Why (& rarr; wiithout the space) → is displayed tiny and lowered in Google Chrome Browser than the Firefox one which is displayed as it supposed to be? Anyone any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Because different browsers have different default formats for characters. Use CSS to define your own standard for all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Try to use one of these:
-o- : for Opera;
-moz- : for FireFox;
-webkit- : for Chrome, Safari,...
I just name three of them because there are more. Different browser will display different things because they can not do all the Css Atribute. Let me take an example:

Hey I want to use border-radius, hmm it looks nice to Chrome but when I change to Opera, it crashed. Let's use the -o- one. Then your code from this:

```
.square{ border-radius: 30px; };
```

to this:

```
.square{ border-radius: 30px; -o-border-radius: 30px;};
```

This will help Opera know that "Hey, this guy one border-radius on my browser. But I don't have it, let's take it from Chrome. " And there you go!

Comment: Do NOT use vendor prefixes!

Comment: :vv I thought it is, I'm sr